# While running the application through "IIS Express" is not working in VS2017 Professional

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have opened the solution in Visual studio 2017 professional, I have built the solution and then I start running it through by clicking "IIS Express" but in IE browser opened and closed suddenly and showing error in VS2017 Professional.

[image]

Comment: Not enough info to give answer.  I would open IE in an exception handler (try/catch) and then capture the exception and get the StackTrace which will give a lot more info.

Comment: You should provide more information. What framework do you use? What kind of project do you have? What version of IIS? Do you have all VS2017 updates?

Comment: @Lavinia N, it was .Net core and yes i have all updated in it VS2017 but still if i running the solution its showing error

Answer (score 0):

You coul'd try to clean hidden .vs folder in your project path. Run clean solution.

Comment: Yes, i tried but cleaning the .vs folders but still same error existing.